# highlighting cells and getting a sum

Tags: worksheet-function

If you highlight two cells, at the bottom of the screen it will tell you the number of cells you highlighted as well as it will add the cells together and give you a sum.  This is working for me but if I highlight two cells that have decimals in them, it doesn't add them together.  Can Excel be fixed so that it adds my decimals when I highlight the two cells together?  Thanks!

Comment: What have you formatted the two cells as? Which Excel version? In Excel 2013, it shouldn't matter whether the format is text, number, general etc. as long as there are only numbers in the cells. I don't know about past versions though...

Answer (score 0):

This does work in excel, likely one of your cells is formatted as a non-number field. Try right using format cells to set them to number fields.